# What does destroying sails do in Deadfire?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

I was playing Pillars of Eternity Deadfire and I got attacked by another ship.

I attacked and destroyed its sails, but that seemed to achieve nothing. It was still pointing towards me with its cannons so it just kept firing and I seemed unable to move so it wasn't pointing the cannons towards me.

So what is the point of destroying the sails? Does it actually achieve anything?

Answer (score 3):

A ship with destroyed sails can no longer turn and only sail forward at half speed. It is essentially a sitting duck. However sails can be repaired during battle.

Comment: So I can control the range but I still can't move behind them so unless our cannons are different ranges it basically does nothing?

Comment: Well, you can turn your ship in a way, that a side with no cannons points towards your ship (i.e. the front or the back of the ship on all ship types except voyagers) and the enemy can no longer fire at you.

Comment: How? You can turn your ship to point no cannons towards them but that doesn't turn their ship. If you turn sideways and move forwards it doesn't move you in front of them, you're still to the side.